# IMAP server for mailboxes used by automated tests

Tags: gratis, linux, email, imap

We are looking for an IMAP server to host some mailboxes (~10) used by automated tests.

Must have features:

- Able to serve emails with IMAP
- Able to receive emails via SMTP (or easy to integrate with Postfix)
- Command-line creation of additional mailboxes
- Available Official Ubuntu Linux packages